# TFTP - Simulating packet loss in JSPIN followed by a timeout

Tags: process, ftp, parallel-processing

I am a beginner in SPIN and Promela.
I am trying to simulate the TFTP (Trivial File Transfer Protocol) using JSPIN software. I have done most of the simulation. However, I am stuck in a problem. It is important for me to simulate the packet loss which is followed by a time out by the sender or the receiver. I could simulate the time out by using the key word "timeout". However, this time out doesn't seem to work as I am expecting. This time out works only when there is no other choice to be executed in the process. However, I would like that time out to work after a specific period of time which happens after a packet loss or duplication in the packet. Therefore, my question is "How to simulate the packet loss in SPIN and follow that by a time out?"

Below is my code.

```
mtype {MSG, ACK, RRQ, WRQ};
chan toS = [3] of {mtype, byte, short};
chan toR = [3] of {mtype, byte, short};
bool readRequest=1;
bool writeRequest=1;

proctype Receiver(chan IN,OUT)
{
byte recvbit;
short size;


do 

:: readRequest==1 -> 

atomic{
readRequest=0;
size=512;
OUT ! RRQ, recvbit, size;
}

:: IN ? WRQ, recvbit, size 
-> OUT ! ACK, recvbit, size;


:: IN ? MSG, recvbit, size 
-> 


response:
atomic {


OUT ! ACK, recvbit, size;

if 
  ::size<512 ->
    if
       ::timeout -> break;
       ::IN ? MSG, recvbit, size -> goto response;
     fi
  ::else
fi;
}

:: timeout -> OUT ! ACK, recvbit, size;

od
}


proctype Sender(chan IN,OUT)
{

byte recvbit;
short size=512;
int repeat=0;
do


:: IN ? RRQ, recvbit, size ->
atomic{

  recvbit=(recvbit+1)%8; 
  size= size - (repeat/2); //after 10 times it becomes 511;
  OUT ! MSG, recvbit,size;
  repeat++;
}

:: writeRequest==1 ->
atomic {
writeRequest=0;
size= size - (repeat/10);
OUT ! WRQ, recvbit,size;
repeat++;

}


:: IN ? ACK, recvbit, size -> 
atomic {


if 
  :: size < 512 -> break;
  :: else ->
  recvbit=(recvbit+1)%8; 
  size= size - (repeat/2); //after 10 times it becomes 511;
  OUT ! MSG, recvbit,size;
  repeat++;
fi


}

:: timeout -> 
atomic {
size= size - (repeat/10);
OUT ! MSG, recvbit,size;
repeat++;

}

od
}


init
{
run Sender(toS, toR);
run Receiver (toR, toS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses the `Demon` process to simulate messages being "lost":

```
chan sendChan = [1] of {bit};
chan replyChan = [1] of {bit};

active proctype Sender() {
  bit replyVal, value = 1;
  do
  :: sendChan ! value -> /*Send msg over sendChan*/
    if
      :: replyChan ? replyVal;  /*Wait for a reply*/
      :: timeout;              /*or timeout if none*/   
    fi
  od
}

active proctype Reciever() {
  bit msg;
  do
    :: sendChan ? msg -> replyChan ! 1; /*Reciever gets msg, sends reply*/
  od
}

active proctype Demon() {
  do
    :: sendChan ? _ ; /*Msg stolen from sendChan!*/
  od
}
```

In the `Demon` process the `_` in `:: sendChan ? _ ;` will read and discard any message in the channel.

Alternatively there is an implementation of the [Alternating Bit Protocol](http://www.imit.kth.se/courses/2G1516/Docs05/Spin/PROMELA/Alternating.Bit.Protocol.promela) (the second model) that uses an extra option in the `Reciever`'s do loop to simulate message loss instead of a separate process.